# Saving state with BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, state, broadcastreceiver

I have a widget and I want to save its state when it's being clicked.

Currently I'm saving the state with SharedPreferences.

This works but it is relatively slow to commit updates to the preferences.

Are there any better solutions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a widget and I want to save its state when it's being clicked.

If by "widget" you mean "widget", this makes no sense. At most, a widget should be communicating with its hosting activity. The activity can save its state at appropriate times using appropriate means.

If by "widget" you mean "app widget", this makes more sense.

> Currently I'm saving the state with SharedPreferences.
>
> This works but it is relatively slow to commit updates to the preferences.
>
> Are there any better solutions?

All writes to flash are slow, by flash's nature. Where possible, committing `SharedPreferences` should be done in the background. On Android 2.3 and higher, you have a new `apply()` method that does that automatically.

Comment: Why doesn't it make sense? it's a widget which has two states.

Comment: @Ran: I don't care whether the widget has one state, two states, or thirty-two states. Android may not be a pure MVC or MVP framework, but there is no question in my mind that widgets are the V in MVC/MVP, and the V should not be persisting *anything* in MVC/MVP.

Comment: so I should start a service just for persisting data?

Comment: @Ran: Not necessarily. Your activity may be able to get away with an `AsyncTask`, for example, for storing things in flash.